# Android Gmail App deleted my email when I swipe left on a IMAP email account

Tags: gmail, imap

Swipe left to **archive** works when my account type is Gmail account.

However, I've added an IMAP account (non-Gmail), the default swipe left action is now **delete** instead of **archive**, and I find no way to make swipe left to archive.

Anyone tried using Gmail app on Android to receive IMAP email?

Answer (score 1):

Read the full article [here](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6562?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en).

1. **Open** the Gmail app.
2. In the top left, tap on **Menu**.
3. At the bottom tap **Settings**.
4. Under the **General Settings**, go to **Swipe Action** and change as per your preference.

Hope it helps.

Thank you.

Comment: If this was a help to you then please accept my answer and close the topic, so that others can found this thread useful.  Thank you Yoga.

Comment: This work for Gmail account only, if my account type is IMAP, and my Swipe Action is default to Archive, but still get my email deleted.